# Finding Last occurrence out of multiple occurrences of a regexp using SED Scripting

Tags: sed, awk

I have a verilog file that has multiple modules defined containing various input and output variables .
I need to find out last occurrence of such variable (input/output) using sed script.
I run the following command

address=`sed -n '100,200{/output/=};100,200{/input/=}' file.txt`
its giving me output as 102 103 104 105 106
while I want only 106.
Please suggest me some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed '100,200{/input\|output/=};d' file.txt | sed '$!d'
```

or perhaps as you intended:

```
address=$(sed '100,200{/input\|output/=};d' file.txt | sed '$!d')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '100,200p' foo.txt | awk '/input/{s=NR} /output/{s=NR} END{print s}'
```

Comment: its not giving me line number but giving the pattern appears after last input/output.plz help!!

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use sed, of course sed/awk could do it. try this:

```
 grep -nE "input|output" test.txt|tail -1|cut -f1 -d:
```

**edit**

do you want this?

```
kent$  echo "102 103 104 105 106"|awk '{print $NF}'
106
```

**edit again**

```
kent$  another=$(echo "102 103 104 105 106"|awk '{print $NF}')

kent$  echo $another
106
```

Comment: there is a variable $adress that has all these values 101 102 103 .. please tell me the way to find out the last value in this varaible.

Comment: @user1468315 check updated answer, not sure if it is what you wanted.

Comment: Still there is one problem , I want to save this value in another variable.

Comment: @user1468315 check the answer again

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
nl -ba < file.txt | sed -n '100,200{/output\|input/h};$x;$p'
```

Comment: Or (dare I say it?) `cat -n file.txt`:)

Comment: `cat -n` is not standardized under IEEE Std 1003.1-2008, but `nl -ba` is.  (But `cat -n` is probably available!)